# One Thunderbolt 3 port only allowing USB 3.0

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, thunderbolt

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports). Both Thunderbolt 3 ports should support USB 3.1.

However, when I look in the device tree in system report (with nothing connected), it lists one USB 3.0 bus and one USB 3.1 bus. This is also actually reflected when I try the same USB hub in both ports (one port has a slower transfer rate).

Not sure how long this has been an issue. I tried resetting the SMC, not sure what else to try or what could even cause this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. What is your exact model of your Mac as reported by Apple Menu > About this Mac?

Comment: MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports). Checked Apple's page and they should both be the same with 3.1 support.